# Why not use %v to print int and string

Tags: string, go, formatting, printf

I know to print `int` we can use `%d`, and `string` we can use `%s`
but we can still use `%v` to print them. So what if I always use `%v` to print them? What issue will happen if I do this?

Comment: I found there could be a recursion using %v  https://play.golang.org/p/4HTN6U4DVU

Comment: You are Overriding the String() of A, which will be called when you convert a to string. Using %v inside String() you are trying to convert the a ( of type A ), triggers the recursive call. Never use %v inside the String() for that type.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Nothing bad will happen, but the `%d` verb instructs the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package to print is as a number (using base 10), and the `%v` verb means to use the *default* format which can be overridden.

See this example:

```
type MyInt int

func (mi MyInt) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("*", int(mi), "*")
}

func main() {
    var mi MyInt = 2
    fmt.Printf("%d %v", mi, mi)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JkUz7O2K3p)):

```
2 *2*
```

When using the `%v` verb, the `fmt` package checks if the value implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface (which is a single `String() string` method), and if so, that method will be called to convert the value to `string` (which may be formatted further if flags are specified).

The complete list of formatting rules is in the package doc of `fmt`, quoting the relevant part:

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> 1. If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.
> 2. If an operand implements the Formatter interface, it will be invoked. Formatter provides fine control of formatting.
> 3. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Answer (score 0):

The **%T** which is used in GO lang by not using **typeOf()** function.
For **typeOf()** function the **reflect** package used.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var num int
    var str string
    var boolean bool
    var flt float64

    fmt.Printf("Type of num: %T\n", num)
    fmt.Printf("Type of str: %T\n", str)
    fmt.Printf("Type of boolean: %T\n", boolean)
    fmt.Printf("Type of flt: %T\n", flt)
}
```

For future learning list of all fmt used Print in [fmtLink](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print)