# Different behavior when printing a bytes.Buffer in Go

Tags: string, pointers, go, struct

When I execute this:

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.WriteString("Hello world")
fmt.Println(buf)
```

it prints `Hello World`.

But if I execute this:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
buf.WriteString("Hello world")
fmt.Println(buf)
```

it prints: `{[72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100] 0 [72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 0}`

I understand that this is the content of the structure [byte.Buffer](https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go?s=402:817#L7) but why it is printed in a different format?

Comment: It currently prints the decimal representations of the ASCII characters you've given in the slices of Buffer. See `String()` of `bytes.Buffer`.

Comment: `new(bytes.Buffer)` returns `*bytes.Buffer`, not `bytes.Buffer`. So, those two `buf` are different :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because a value of type `*bytes.Buffer` has a `String()` method (the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of `*bytes.Buffer` contains the `String()` method), and a value of type `bytes.Buffer` does not.

And the `fmt` package checks if the value being printed has a `String() string` method, and if so, it is called to produce the string representation of the value.

Quoting from package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> 1. If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.
> 2. If an operand implements the Formatter interface, it will be invoked. Formatter provides fine control of formatting.
> 3. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. **If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).**

The `Buffer.String()` method returns its content as a `string`, that's what you see printed when you pass a pointer of type `*bytes.Buffer`. And when you pass a non-pointer value of type `bytes.Buffer`, it is simply printed like a normal struct value, for which the default format is:

```
{field0 field1 ...}
```

**See related / similar questions:**

[The difference between t and *t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065856/the-difference-between-t-and-t/43065979#43065979)

[Why not use %v to print int and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159169/why-not-use-v-to-print-int-and-string/41159231#41159231)

[Why does Error() have priority over String()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159980/why-does-error-have-priority-over-string/30160112#30160112)