# How to load method for struct in Array in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, methods

Hello Now I am trying to convert Java to Go.

But I have problem with using method declared for structure.

Before put structure in Array, Method could be loaded and used.

After put it in array, I cannot call method for it.

Can you check below codes?

Result said me that dvdCollection.DVD undefined (type [15]*DVD has no field or method DVD)

```
type DVD struct {
    name        string
    releaseYear int
    director    string
}

func (d *DVD) AddDVD(name string, releaseYear int, director string) {
    d.name = name
    d.releaseYear = releaseYear
    d.director = director
}

func main() {
    dvdCollection := [15]DVD{}
    dvdCollection.AddDVD("Terminator1", 1984, "James Cameron")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dvdCollection` is a value of an array type (`[15]DVD`). The `AddDVD()` method is defined on the `DVD` type (more specifically `*DVD`). You can only call `AddDVD()` on a `*DVD` value.

For example:

```
dvdCollection[0].AddDVD("Terminator1", 1984, "James Cameron")
// which means (&dvdCollection[0]).AddDVD("Terminator1", 1984, "James Cameron")
fmt.Println(dvdCollection[0])
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/obBZ0bpbcuM)):

```
{Terminator1 1984 James Cameron}
```

Also note that you are using an [array](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) (`[15]DVD`). It's rare to use an array in Go, you should likely want to use a [slice](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types). For an introduction and details, see blog post: [Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://go.dev/blog/slices)

Comment: Thank you for your support  
Plus question 

how to define strings for it? before it worked, but now it doesn't work.

func (d *DVD) String() string {
 s := fmt.Sprintf("%s directed by %s released in %d", d.name, d.director, d.releaseYear)
 return s
}

fmt.Println(dvdCollection[0])


Result 
{Terminator1 1984 James Cameron}

Comment: @Gopyther Because your array contains non-pointer `DVD` values, and you defined your `String()` method with pointer receiver `*DVD`. Either specify it on non-pointer receiver like `func (d DVD) String()` or print a pointer value like `&dvdCollection[0]`. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005752/different-behavior-when-printing-a-bytes-buffer-in-go/53005853#53005853